# How to Install google api's from 3 to 7 manually?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I have google api's 9 already installed but I need previous version of google api's.I tried to install them using "Windows->Android SDK and AVD manager -> Available packages" but it is showing no updates.How can I install them ? Please help me I need them because I'm developing a GPS based application which needs google API's.Since the emulator crashes on sending geo coordinates based on google api 9 I need older versions. Please help !!!!

Comment: try changing the path of ur SDK folder

Comment: "Since the emulator crashes on sending geo coordinates based on google api 9 I need older versions." -- reportedly, this was fixed in the updates released this past Tuesday.

Comment: @CommonsWare : How can I get those update.Please tell me the steps to update it in my eclipse.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html and http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#updating (though note that the screenshots are out of date in the first link)

Comment: @CommonsWare - sorry to inform you but I upgraded to SDK4.0 yesterday plus all the tools and the plugin, built a new Google API 9 emulator and send it a geo fix. It died in a heap, just like before.

Comment: @NickT: I just tried it and it works for me. I ran the Maps app, sent a fix over from DDMS, and it immediately displayed the location on the map.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Just repeated the process to be sure. Made a new AVD, sent the coords from DDMS, same dead emulator as before. My setup is Windows 64 bit, maybe it's OK on Linux?

Comment: @NickT: Possibly. Make sure you downloaded the updates for API Level 9 and 10, though. I have "Rev" of 2 for both of those.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Yes, got rev 2 for both of those. Tried an OSM project, API level 9 without Google API. Target normal 2.3.1, built with 2.3.1, sent fix from DDMS, killed it stone dead again. I can live with I suppose but it's a bit of a pain

Comment: @NickT: Ah, try API Level 10. I get the same problem as before on API Level 9, but 10 is working. API Level 9 is pretty much not in use anyway (0.5% of devices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to install older versions by invoking tools/android directly. For example, on my Linux dev machine, I run:

```
phil@Ubuntu64-5810T:/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86$ tools/android list sdk
<snip>
Packages available for installation or update: 20
   1- Documentation for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1
   2- SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 1
   3- SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
   4- SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
   5- SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
   6- SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
   7- SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
   8- SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
   9- Samples for SDK API 14, revision 1
  10- Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
  11- Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
  12- Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 14, revision 1
  13- Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 13, revision 1
  14- Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 12, revision 1
  15- Google TV by Google Inc., Android API 12, revision 2
  16- Google APIs by Google Inc., Android API 10, revision 2
  17- Android Support package, revision 4
  18- Google Admob Ads Sdk package, revision 3
  19- Google Market Billing package, revision 1
  20- Google Webdriver package, revision 1
```

You can install various SDKs via

phil@Ubuntu64-5810T:/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86$ tools/android sdk

This will then pop up a GUI, similar to[image: this]

Just check the 'obsolete' box and all the older APIs should show up.